# Multipoint from database using Geotools

Tags: java, postgis, geotools

I just want to know how to create an instance of a `Multipoint` from a PostGIS database.

I do the query, then get a `ResultSet` named `area`. The column with `MultiPolygon` attributes is named `geom`, so I do the following:

```
MultiPolygon m = (MultiPolygon)area.getObject("geom");
```

Forced cast doesn't work though!

Comment: Can you add the query to the question description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't be referencing the ResultSet directly but should work through the datastore interface which takes care of the conversion for you. See the [Query Tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/tutorials/filter/query.html) for an example of searching a dataset and retrieving geometries.

You'll need something like:

```
 SimpleFeatureSource source = dataStore.getFeatureSource(typeName);

    FeatureType schema = source.getSchema();
    String name = schema.getGeometryDescriptor().getLocalName();

    Filter filter = CQL.toFilter(text.getText());

    Query query = new Query(typeName, filter, new String[] { name });

    SimpleFeatureCollection features = source.getFeatures(query);
```